# RegEx: Put Next Two Lines (Tabbed) On First With Return

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to put every 2nd and 3rd line on the preceding first line without matching any sort of pattern other than \n, but it doesn't seem to work across the board with my data set when trying to put tabs in between them.

Essentially, the logic I'm looking for should be every 2 \n replace with \t but skipping the 3rd \n.

**Example:**

A \n

B \n

C \n

**Becomes:**

A \t B \t C\n

**Find:**

`(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n`

**Replace:**

`\1\t\2\t`

Comment: Where is the regex used? How? Can there be more lines?

Comment: Yes, it will be used for many lines with no defined end other than matching further \n instances.

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't the replace be `\1\t\2\t\3`?

Comment: `\1\t\2\t\3` puts everything on one line for me.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/JcJ2sA/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)
```

Replace with  `\1\t\2\t\3`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JcJ2sA/1).

Make sure the `^` matches the line start position, i.e. if necessary use the right modifier (like `(?m)`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*)` - Group 1:  a line
- `\n` - a newline char
- `(.*)` - Group 2:  a line and then
- `\n` - a newline char
- `(.*)` - Group 3:  a line

The replacement is Group 1 + TAB + Group 2 + TAB + Group 3.